# ASP.NET Core Web Application + Services: Automate deployments

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, azure-devops, devops

In my old projects I was deploying asp.net applications to different environments with Octopus deployment tool.

I have a new project - Asp.net Core App with couple of Services.
There is a Azure Dev Ops pipeline that builds and deploys applications into docker hub.

I found thousands of tutorials how one can deploy applications into Azure App-Service but this is not what I need. I need to make an automated deployment to on premise servers (not into Azure) with Azure DevOps release pipeline.

How do I do this ? Do I still need to use Docker/Compose or not ? Where do I start ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert, but I'll try to help - I've seen the pipeline that does that in the past. I hope this helps but please keep in mind **this is deployment to on-prem machine and not a docker container.** I'll assume that the process is going to be similar.

- You need an agent installed on a target machine ([docs](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/IISWebAppDeploymentOnMachineGroupV0/README.md))
- Create a Deployment group ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/deployment-groups/?view=azure-devops)) (*Deployment Groups are logical groups of deployment target machines with agents installed on each of them*)
- There should be a Stage in Azure Release pipelines called *IIS website deployment*
  (*Deployment Group: Deploy an ASP.NET or ASP.NET Core web application to an IIS website on physical or virtual machines (VM).*) - I think that's the one, but just search for IIS in Stages and choose whatever suits you.
- This will create a Stage with 2 tasks in it. In the stage settings (IIS Deployment), select the deployment group you've created.